# "Благодарю всех(?) принявших участие в выборах..." Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастия

Пришла СМС от губернатора, и текст немного режет глаза.
Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?

> Благодарю всех, принявших участие в выборах Президента России! Д. Азаров

У меня есть сомнения в необходимости запятой, но я не могу их обосновать.
Мне кажется, что **все принявшие, все выжившие, все потерпевшие**, — это нечто единое,  не требующее разделения запятой.

А также слово "всех" можно выбросить из фразы без потери смысла, поскольку оно несет уточняющую нагрузку: *благодарю принявших* — каких принявших? — *всех принявших*.
Губернатор явно не ***всех*** благодарит, а только ***всех принявших***.

Нужна ли запятая в данном случае?

Comment: Так "все принявшие" — «нечто единое», или "всех" можно выбросить из фразы без потери?

Comment: @shampar "всех" можно выбросить, так как оно только уточняет каких именно принявших касается благодарность. Можно аналогично уточнить другими словами: Благодарю **некоторых принявших участие**, **отдельных принявших участие** и т.п. И в таком случае запятая точно становится ненужной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обособление факультативное, но вариант без запятой мне кажется более подходящим: Благодарю всех **принявших учАстие //в выборах** Президента России! Д. Азаров.

В этом случае логически выделены **участники голосования**, а местоимение является только дополнительным определением. Интонационно такая фраза читается более естественно.

ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=140

§ 50. Не обособляются определения нераспространенные и с зависимыми словами, стоящие после местоимений отрицательных, неопределенных, указательных, определительных, образующие с ними **единую группу** (ударение падает на определение):

Однако при наличии уточняющего и ограничительного значения определения обособляются: Все отъезжающие и провожающие должны пройти в зал ожидания (причастия имеют при себе определение — местоимение все). — Все, отъезжающие и провожающие, расположились в зале ожидания (определения-причастия уточняют значение местоимения все);

Answer (score 0):

Пунктуационных ошибок в тексте нет.

> нужна ли запятая между словами "всех" и "принявших":

Запятая здесь факультативна. Грамматика допускает и понимание "принявших (участие)" и как причастия в составе причастного оборота (тогда и запятая неоходима), и как элемент семантически нечленимого оборота "все принявшие" (тут запятая не требуется). Выбор определяется авторским смыслом. Если акцент на **всех**, то логично трактовать именно причастием в составе причастного оборота. Так, видимо, и понимает автор "губернаторского" текста. Если же акцент падает на "принявших участие", то запятая не нужна.

Я бы не стал от запятой отказываться.

> Мне кажется "все принявшие", "все выжившие", "все потерпевшие" - это
>   нечто единое, что не требуется разделять запятой.

В последних двух случаях вы правы, здесь по смыслу вариант с запятой не очень смотрится, хотя исключать абсолютно тоже нельзя. Но это слова по семантической функции более склонны к субстантивации. Смотрите, "Выжившие" - самодостаточное. А вот "принявшие" без пояснения чего или в чем (у нас - в выборах) пригодно разве как характеристика человека в состоянии алкогольного опьянения - "принявший (на грудь)".

Comment: Мне кажется, акцент не на "всех", а на всех "всех принявших". Есть ли какая-нибудь отсылка к правилу, хотя бы подтверждение факультативности?

Comment: А вот если заменить **всех** на **некоторых**? _Благодарю некоторых принявших участие..._ Семантика не изменится, но запятая уже точно не нужна будет, верно?